# Oracle Date and EJB Date

Tags: java, oracle, date, ejb

I have got a column of type DATE in my Oracle DB. 06.09.12 is one of the values stored there. I also have an EJB-entity mapped to the table, which has a member field "date" of type java.util.Date. However, the getter method returns the date stored in the table plus one day, e. g. 07.09.12 instead of  06.09.12. How can I get exactly the date stored? Should I consider using Timestamp?

Comment: how are you retreiving the date from DB ?

Comment: does the date in the DB mimic the time-zone? (what is the NLS_DATE_FORMAT value?). What is the user-timezone value on the machine you run java code?

Comment: Thanks, the issue was connected with different timezones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have different timezones - the timezone on the DB is different from the timezone set in Java. The underlying time is actually the same, but, for example, the date on the DB is interpreted in GMT and the Java as Eastern time. After midnight at GMT, GMT is one day ahead for 7 or so hours.

Both these timezones default to the timezone of the server, but can be overridden by the DB installation and the Java VM.

To test if this is the case, on Oracle:

```
select dbtimezone,sessiontimezone from dual;
```

And on Java:

```
TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
System.out.println("TimeZone: "+tz.getDisplayName());
```